# Running supremum of a right-continuous function: prove that $\left\{x\geq 0\left|\sup_{0\leq y\leq x}f(y)\geq K\right.\right\}$ is closed.

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a right-continuous function. Consider the set
$$
E=\left\{x\geq 0\left|\sup_{0\leq y\leq x}f(y)\geq K\right.\right\},
$$
where $K$ is a constant. It is pretty intuitive that the right-continuity of $f$ makes $E$ a closed set, that is $x_{E}=\inf E\in E$. Any suggestion? Below I report my attempt.

After some thoughts, I came up with this proof. Hope that someone can verify its correctness.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not correct. The interval $(x_0,x_0+\delta)$ does not contain $x_0$, so it is not a nbd of $x_0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, and a part from that the fact that $f(x)<K$ does not exclude $\sup f=K$, so we cannot say that the set is contained in the complement.